# Sphericity fort t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, anova, variance

In my statisticus course I can remember that an ANOVA requires normality AND sphericity (homogenous variance).  Violation of the latter can be compensated for with a Greenhouse-Geiser correction.

A one-way ANOVA is equivalent to a t-test. In my textbooks on t-tests, however, I can't find that this test requires sphericity (homogeneous variances). Given the analogy between ANOVA and t-tests I am in doubt. Is it true that sphericity must be true for t-tests as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers are correct. There are versions of t-test that assume equal variance and versions that do not e.g. Welch t-test. The chances are, if you are using a t-test from from some software, it does not assume equal variances and it performs welch t-test automatically for you (this is how it is in R, i don't know about other programs)

Comment: Also worth to mention that Welch correction is just an approximation, but a very good one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test#Assumptions (the comparison with ANOVA is also there)